# Unable to print json array values in php

Tags: php

Hi following was my output am prinitng,

```
{"Confirmation":"200710035843DH4","Message":"success","Status":"success"}
```

I need to store each of the values confirmation,message ,status in seperate php varaiables, how can i do that. Following is my code

```
var_dump(json_decode($server_output));
echo $server_output["Confirmation"];
```

Comment: Not sure how that output relates to your json. But the answer is to decode the json with second parameter true to an array. Then extract($array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in many different ways, have a look for different approaches and their demo's.

Using `extract()`,

```
<?php
$str = '{"Confirmation":"200710035843DH4","Message":"success","Status":"success"}';
extract(json_decode($str,true));
echo $Confirmation;
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/3U43b

Using `foreach()`,

```
<?php
$str = '{"Confirmation":"200710035843DH4","Message":"success","Status":"success"}';
$array = json_decode($str,true);
foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) { $$key = $value; }
echo $Confirmation;
?>
```

**DEMO:**: https://3v4l.org/jLnRE

Using `array destructure` (as of **php 7.1**),

```
<?php
$str = '{"Confirmation":"200710035843DH4","Message":"success","Status":"success"}';
['Confirmation'=>$confirmation, 'Message'=>$message, 'Status'=>$status] =  json_decode($str,true);
echo $confirmation;
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/rrFa8

Using `list()`,

```
<?php
$str = '{"Confirmation":"200710035843DH4","Message":"success","Status":"success"}';
list('Confirmation'=>$confirmation, 'Message'=>$message, 'Status'=>$status) =  json_decode($str,true);
echo $confirmation;
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/Zpt60

Answer (score 1):

You could use `extract()`, however this imports variables from your array into the current symbol table. If you want control over the variable names, you can use `list()`:

```
<?php
$json = '{"Confirmation":"200710035843DH4","Message":"success","Status":"success"}';
$arr = json_decode($json, true);

list('Confirmation' => $conf, 'Message' => $msg, 'Status' => $status) = $arr;

echo $conf;
echo $msg;
echo $status;
```

working [demo](https://3v4l.org/kabA8)